# Handling unsolicited proofs of famous mathematical problems

Tags: etiquette, peer-review

I have been receiving mails from (most probably amateurs), who claims to have proved famous mathematical problems, like the ABC Conjecture or Goldbach Conjecture. But invariably, they all contained mistakes. I decided not to waste my time on such unsolicited documents. But recently something interesting happened.

About 14 days earlier, I have received a mail from an Indian undergraduate student who claimed to have proved the [Sylvester-Gallai Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) in an elementary way. What is more amusing is that he claimed to have proved it using Mathematical Induction and a basic Euclidean Axiom. I decided to ignore it as usual. But yesterday I got his mail, telling me that-

> I suppose you haven't considered my document worthy of your time and so you haven't gone through it at all, or it may be that you are so busy that you haven't found time to check your email account. If that's the case then just ignore this mail. But if it's the first case then I would like to tell you something.
>
> Perhaps you have heard about the Indian Mathematician Srinivasa Ramanujan. He also sent his mathematical works to renowned mathematicians like Baker and Hobson but they didn't reply. Later he sent his manuscript to Hardy and his genius was recognized. But just suppose that Hardy also considered his work to be the work of a crank, without even going through it. Consider this be the case even if he would sent it to other mathematicians. How long could he continue sending his unsolicited formulas and theorems (which were without proof!) to other mathematicians and be rejected? Of course, finitely many times. After that, he perhaps wouldn't write to any mathematician even if he had, suppose for example proved the Riemann Hypothesis. Why would he? He was likely to be rejected.
>
> So I suggest you at least to go through my document thoroughly and tell me precisely about it.
>
> Please don't behave like Baker or Hobson.

What should I do now? Should I remain silent or go through the document? Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: I have no idea how many such emails a mathematics professor receive every day, but I think you can give some of it as exercises to some undergraduate students who have an interest for research to find out the mistakes, it may be fun and a learning opportunity for them.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: Mods can't purge edit histories. You have to contact SE staff to do that.

Comment: I would suggest this gentleman to read up on opportunity costs and expected value.

Comment: Baker and Hobson are almost invariably omitted, or not named, in the canonical Ramanujan-Hardy story. The fact your correspondent mentions them makes me think his manuscript is worth a look.

Comment: I like the idea of farming it out as an extra-credit problem... and I agree that the badgering second note is a better reason to ignore it than to follow up on it. That's a marketing argument, not math.

Comment: I am reminded of the famous quote of Carl Sagan: "But the fact that some geniuses were laughed at does not imply that all who are laughed at are geniuses. They laughed at Columbus, they laughed at Fulton, they laughed at the Wright Brothers. But they also laughed at Bozo the Clown."

Comment: @TheMathemagician: How does the correspondent's demonstrated above-average knowledge of a historical anecdote make it more likely that his mathematical manuscript is worth reading?

Comment: If I recall correctly, India's mathematics program was weak to non-existent back in Ramanujan's time. Now with Harish-Chandra Research Institute and Tata, there are plenty of people in India that can help him and give him feedback if it is not crank work. I would put effort in helping letters from people from less mathematically developed countries.

Comment: @Mark Meckes Well it doesn't, but at least you'll be dealing with a better class of crank. Seriously though, all the correspondent needs to do is post his two-page proof to mathoverflow.net and he'll get it critiqued for free.

Comment: @TheMathemagician: If by "critiqued" you mean "deleted within minutes" I agree with you.  Like most mathematicians, the MO community takes a dim view of anything that smacks of crankery, which this certainly does.  They also frown on "please check this proof" posts, preferring specific questions.

Comment: I had no idea how common this sort of behaviour was. I concede I am probably heavily over-estimating the probability of the work having any merit.

Comment: @TheMathemagician: It is extremely common. If you're interested in learning more about the taxonomy of people who submit crazy stuff to professional mathematicians, Underwood Dudley's book "Mathematical Cranks" is an enjoyable read.

Comment: Your description seems to hint -- but not say explicitly -- that the proof you got is without value.  The Sylvester-Gallai Theorem didn't ring a bell with me, so I looked it up on wikipedia and edited in the wikipedia link.  That article gives two different proofs, each taking up about half a page.  The first one (from a 1986 paper of Kelly) is completely elementary and uses a little Euclidean geometry.  Two pages thus sounds long for an elementary proof, but not necessarily prohibitively long.  Is it supposed to be clear that the student's work is of no value?  Do you feel this way?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Good thought to look it up.  I also assumed from the context that Sylvester-Gallai was a hard theorem.  If it is actually elementary, then it's more plausible that the student's work is correct, but it also makes the comparison with Ramanujan more absurd.

Comment: @Nate: I agree.  I also agree with the other answers that remark that India in 2014 is a very different place from India in 1912, and that if the correspondent is an undergraduate student that means he has faculty members who are being paid to (in part) evaluate his work and answer his questions.  I would myself feel more sympathy to someone who is nowhere near any academic environment and still trying to do mathematical research.

Comment: Inspired by some of the comments and answers here: If this is really such a nuisance, why not set up a platform somewhere between a Stack Exchange and classical peer review for this, where everybody can submit such proofs and the same people are somewhat encouraged (or forced) to review other submitter’s proofs? Also, everybody is free to review proofs. If any proof is any good, this should be recognised almost immediately. Everybody bothered by such requests can just reply with a link to that platform.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: "If any proof is any good, this should be recognised almost immediately." Please teach me this skill of almost immediately recognizing whether proofs are any good! For lack of it, I must spend hours (or days...) going over every proof I see, including my own, those of my students and of my most trusted collaborators.  In the above cases, to a greater or lesser extent I have the advantage of being familiar with the author's writing style and being able to count on some shared knowledge and assumptions.  Reading a proof from a stranger who has not written many papers is much harder.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: You misunderstood me. By “any good”, I meant that it actually requires the amount of time you describe to find a mistake or rule them out (which seems not to be the case for the submissions we are talking about here).

Comment: One strategy is to refer them to [I believe I have solved a famous open problem. How do I convince people in the field that I am not a crank?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18491/) and particularly [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/18570/820) to help them phrase their emails better and understand your constraints and perspectives.

Comment: Not a total "on-topic" comment, but it may be helpful to somebody: I heard that an easy way to handle these emails is to answer like: "Dear [...], the manuscript you sent is not in my area of expertise [or insert some other excuse], but I know an expert on this topic. Please send you paper to [enter email of the sender of the previous unsolicited email you got] and he/she will be happy to discuss this with you." I heard that this worked in times of paper-mail…

Comment: Dirk, I assume you'd them give them the name of.your best frenemy in the discipline? :-)

Comment: Reading through all the responses, I'm glad that I'm in the social sciences. Our cranks are easier to figure out what with the references to Noah's Ark and the liberal use of ALL-CAPS.

Comment: I still think the "Museum of Unworkable Devices" website is one of the most elegant responses to this sort of thing I've seen. It specifically addresses perpetual motion machines, dividing them into related families and showing why they don't work. It may not stop any genuine cranks, but it's a good place to point those who aren't invoking non-physics.

Comment: "Dear [name]:

Your last email suggests that you do not understand how research results are disseminated. If you have an interesting result in your hands, you should, in this order, (i) discuss it with some local experts; (ii) upload it to the arxiv; (iii) submit an abstract to a conference; (iv) submit a paper to a journal. It is hardly beneficial to your research and your reputation to send it to a random person halfway around the world and then call them irrationally obtuse when they decline to read unsolicited mail from strangers from halfway around the world.

Sincerely, [your name]"

Comment: The Sylvester-Gallai theorem is in fact a canonical example of a problem that is easily solved using elementary geometry via the extremal principle, and the extremal principle is a basic consequence of induction. However, the clearest indicator that something is wrong is that the student can name the theorem (which implies he likely saw it on wikipedia) but cannot grasp that the extremal principle is essentially equivalent to induction. The other indicator is the arrogant attitude, which is typical of [semi-]cranks.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think there's little or nothing you can realistically do for most amateurs sending unsolicited manuscripts.  What they don't seem to realize is how common this is and what a bad state most of the manuscripts are in:

1. I average several amateur e-mails per week (and I shudder to think of how many Andrew Wiles or Terry Tao must get).  If I carefully read each paper and sent comments, that alone would occupy a substantial fraction of my professional activities, so I have to prioritize.
2. I at least flip through the papers, and most of them are obviously crackpot work.  Occasionally I see one that doesn't look ridiculous, and I try to be encouraging when appropriate, but I have yet to receive a publishable paper from an amateur.  The best I can do is generally to offer encouraging advice, and even that's uncommon.
3. Some people seem beyond hope (for example, the ones who send word salad), but some could presumably become solid researchers given the right education and mentoring.  However, this is not something I have a lot of time to provide.  I've got plenty of in-person students, some of whom would probably like more interaction, and I wouldn't feel comfortable telling them "Sorry, I'm busy trying to explain to some guy on the internet why his fuzzy understanding of quantum mechanics doesn't actually yield a short proof of Fermat's Last Theorem."  Even if the amateur seems promising, they aren't likely to be dramatically more promising than my students, and mentoring over the internet is less effective, so it's still an awkward trade-off.
4. Some amateurs react very poorly to feedback.  If you suggest their results are known (while complimenting them on their rediscovery), they angrily suggest that you must not have understood what they meant or are trying to deny them credit for their work.  If you don't believe their results, they accuse you of incompetence or laziness.  If you encourage them to apply to graduate school, they scoff at what academia would have to teach them.  This is of course only a minority of amateurs, but it's just common enough to discourage giving honest feedback: there's too much of a risk of feeling like you wasted time offering feedback to someone who only wanted validation and responded with insults.
5. Part of the problem is grandiose visions.  When people spend too much time daydreaming about being the next Ramanujan or finding the proof that didn't fit in Fermat's margin, it's really unsatisfying to learn that their story isn't actually as remarkable as they hoped.  It's much easier psychologically to move to the parallel story of the genius oppressed by academia, rather than starting an academic career from scratch.  (And even people who show no sign of grandiosity in their original e-mail sometimes have it hiding below the surface: I imagine that anyone who sends unsolicited accounts of their discoveries to experts is hoping for some degree of acclaim.)

So what to do about this?  In an ideal world, I'd give lots of time and attention to everyone who wrote, but these are scarce resources.  In practice, I handle it this way:

1. If the paper genuinely engages with my work and shows no signs of craziness (e.g., drawing religious conclusions from mathematics), I give at least a brief reply.  Same thing if I have some other good reason to believe it was sent specifically to me, and not just as one of many recipients.
2. If the paper looks relatively promising but has nothing specific to do with me, I'll reply if I have time and feel that the reply would be well received.
3. If the paper is on a topic I particularly know and care about but doesn't involve my work and doesn't seem especially promising, I might reply.
4. Otherwise, I probably won't reply, and almost certainly not if the paper deals with famous unsolved problems.

Answer (score 34):

Continue to treat it as spam, and ignore it.

For every Ramanujan, there are many many thousands of time-wasters.

The reward:cost ratio, weighted by the ratio of misunderstood geniuses to time-wasters, is very very low.

If someone has any ability, they should be able to demonstrate it quickly. And if they've got any sense, they'll realise they need to demonstrate it up front to get taken seriously.

So if someone hasn't put a pre-print up somewhere (much easier to do now than in Ramanujan's day), and has no pre-published material, ignoring them is now an even safer bet than it ever was before.

In this particular case, your [correspondant](https://mathoverflow.net/users/48849/william-hilbert) may have already tried posting on Math Overflow, although it may be someone else with the same name. Either way, if you're feeling generous with your time, you could prepare a canned response which went to all such neglected geniuses / timewasters that pointed them to Math Overflow, as a good place to engage with the Maths Research community and demonstrate that they are actually able.

Comment: I don't think he is the same person of whom I have been talking about. This person is an undergraduate. But it seems that the person you have pointed out is a professional mathematician. However, the comment- "..The reward:cost ratio, weighted by the ratio of misunderstood geniuses to time wasters, is very very low." is something useful to me. But do you actually have a statistics or it is just your intuition?

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate: how would you say one should demonstrate their ability up front, other than by sending a manuscript? (Perhaps by submitting it to a journal?)

Comment: @DavidZ: I think the question *in this case* is: why isn't the student showing the manuscript to faculty at his university?  Even if no one there is qualified to read it (which seems unlikely since the topic is combinatorial plane geometry), they can still work with him to find someone who can.

Answer (score 28):

The fact that he compares himself to Ramanujan just gives you all the more reason to ignore his mails.

If his work had any merit, his follow-up email would have been focused on that merit and how it might have been hard to see at first glance.

Comment: I don't think that if someone compares himself to Ramanujan, his works become useless. In reviewing what only matters is the work itself. It is immaterial whether he compares himself to Ramanujan or Gauss.

Comment: @AlfredGauss Sure, but the fact that his choice of follow-up is that comparison rather than an explanation of the merit of his work says a lot.

Comment: but just as the @AlfredGauss worrying about wasting time for a crank, the sender is worrying about being seen as a crank. It's the worry that makes him has to focus on where he is a crank or not, not the content of the paper. And even if he want to say so, how should he replies if there is no question for him?

Comment: In fact the tactic of comparing himself to Ramanujan is a well-established logical fallacy: https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Galileo_gambit

Answer (score 24):

Many years ago, my university used to send letters that explained they received so many proof they didn't have the time to check them all, so each sender received a copy of the previous proof the university had received and asked them to check that one to help the university with their workload. That worked very well.

I think it was my professor in analysis, who received one letter where someone had worked out an excellent approximation of pi as a fraction of rational numbers (I think it was the next approximation better than 355/113). And he found that the result this man found was actually absolutely correct, not quite as mind-blowing as the sender probably hoped, but nevertheless correct, and he replied with a long letter acknowledging the correct results and a list of sources that would help an interested amateur.

That man was a single and outstanding exception. And the OP starter complaining about mistakes: Most of the time things are so bad, there are not even things that could be called "mistakes".

Comment: What's special about approximations of pi as fractions of rational numbers? I just found a really good one: 314159265359/100000000000

Comment: To be precise, the convergents $a_n/b_n$ of the continued fraction expansion of a given real number $x$ are provably the [best rational approximations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations) with denominator $\leq b_n$.

Comment: They're also slightly more profound than that: a rational is a convergent $a_n/b_n$ to $\alpha$ if and only if $|\alpha - a_n/b_n| < 1/b_n^2$. The next convergent to pi is rather large, so presumably the man's work had some interesting nontrivial (though not new) merit.

Comment: @daviewales: That's actually a rubbish and rather thoughtless approximation, since better approximations with much smaller numbers are known.

Comment: OK. I think I misunderstood your meaning. When you said "better than 355/113", I thought you meant "closer to pi", rather than "closer to pi, with small integers and mathematical rigour".

Comment: The idea in the second paragraph is excellent!

Answer (score 15):

Have you considered offering your professional services for a nominal fee?  I would think $250-500 that a starting price for detailed analysis, and potential support of a mathematical proof would be a fair price.  Of course for one that will require considerably more effort, that fee could be increased.

If you are loathe to take the money you could always either donate the fees, or return them to the author.  The primary purpose of the fee is to filter out the random amatuer submissions that have not been well thought or checked out.  I assume that you would not mind doing a few serious reviews a year, if you could avoid the spam.

Comment: Noah Snyder did this for a bit and made some good money; he tells the story here http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/should-experts-in-tcs-charge-money-to-read-proofs-that-p-np/4508#4508 .

Comment: Ramanujan was very poor remember?

Comment: @PatrickT - If he was serious about the proof then finding the nominal fee or offering some other service in exchange should not be a problem.  The purpose of the fee is put up a barrier in front those who are not serious that is easy to overcome with a little effort so that those that are serious can get through.

Comment: There is a market for this: [What I learned as a hired consultant for autodidact physicists](https://aeon.co/ideas/what-i-learned-as-a-hired-consultant-for-autodidact-physicists)

Comment: Discuss this with your employer first, you might get into legal trouble.

Answer (score 8):

In a reply, suggest a journal to send it to. Then if it gets accepted for review, the reviewer may have an easy task in front of them. (Either that or genius will be recognised.) Everyone will be happy either way.

Comment: Can you suggest some journal to which he may send his approximately-2-page 'elementary proof' of the Sylvester-Gallai Theorem?

Comment: @AlfredGauss Hahaha, well, the burden of journal-finding lies with him. He's got access to the Internet. Let me just point out that he may have no idea how peer-review and publishing work in mathematics. Luckily, nowadays you don't have to explain it to them. It suffices to suggest Google search terms.

Comment: @AlfredGauss: Possibly [this one](http://www.universalrejection.org)?

Comment: @NateEldredge The source or the length of a proof can't be a basis for its rejection. The AKS paper is only 9 pages http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test

Answer (score 4):

I guess I don't see the big moral quandary. You're a talented person who has worked a long time to develop his skills, and you are under absolutely no obligation to give those skills and your time away for free to every Tom, Dick, and Harriet. If you *want to* that's fine, but the fact that you feel pressured to do this is not good.

This person's case is really not that compelling to me: he has proved a result which has already been proved and by elementary methods also (according to a previous poster). Maybe it could be published but for this person to suggest his ability is comparable to Ramanujan's in some way based on *this* result seems absolutely ludicrous. To me, his appeal to Ramanujan, which is based solely on their circumstances and nationality, seems manipulative, and his comparison of himself to Ramanujan, shows a sort of hubris I find appalling. If Ramanujan had sent a proof of a result which had already been proved by elementary means to Hardy, do you *really*  think Hardy would have given it a second thought?  I seriously doubt it. Based on the information given, maybe he has some talent, but I don't see evidence of a world-class genius being lost here.

Answer (score 3):

The reasoning developed in the second e-mail ("please do not ignore the hidden genius") was true when you first started receiving this type of e-mail, which is why you read these first theorems.

However, after a few try, you figured that the genius/spam ratio (as @EnergyNumbers pointed out) was not worth considering all these e-mail (maybe unconsciously...). In short, I think nothing changed with this e-mail.

If you really want to consider all these emails without spending toot much time, as @bingung said, and if you are giving lectures, you can assign them to students. It would be indeed a great exercice to try to demonstrate the theorems are not valid.

A third option, to give you a good conscience, and since the genius/spam ratio is probably really low, you can review 1/10th of the theorems you receive. It will not dramatically decrease the change to discover a math genius...

Answer (score 3):

After getting rid of spam in your email box by the spam filter, pass every unrequested mail through the crackpot index:

It will give points for, for example:

- mentioning Einstein, Feynman or Hawkins. (I suppose mentioning Ramanujan would be the same but in the mathematical field instead of physical field).
- complaining about the establishment
- vacuous statements

Read everything about it in: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/crackpot.html

I don't believe you'll need more then 2-3 minutes for that.

However, also don't forget to take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_amateur_mathematicians, since there is mathematics outside academical mathematics too.

Comment: Yes, obviously I meant Einstien, Feynmann and Hankiws, in the case of physics. They are as equally important as Erdoos, Rieman, or Ramaniuya.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked more in the mathematical sciences than anywhere else. An interesting text on the topic (with advice) is **A Budget of Trisections** by Underwood Dudley. It is probably available somewhere cheaper than on amazon [dudley](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387965688) *(I found some related work on scribd.com.)* If you are dealing with an intelligent and younger person, it might be useful to point out that your time is limited and that they might benefit from reading that text. The lesson I learned there is that practically no older amateur will take your advice when it is pointed out that they tried to prove something extremely hard or know-to-be-unprovable. Today this all happens online, and you should also look at John Baez's crackpot index at http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/crackpot.html , I assume there must be a mathematical version. (translate Einstein to Ramanujan, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Ramanujan is actually a difficult case because he was in fact an amateur crackpot, and his contribution to real math is not clear to me. But yes, he was a genius. He did not reveal the methods by which he derived his magic formula, even though I am convinced he could explain it if he wanted to. He did not want to reveal his secret craft, he only wanted the fame. I say dunk it in the wastebasket in this case, and if you ever come across work which sounds scientific tell the author to submit it to [arxiv.](http://arxiv.org/)

Comment: Referring to arXiv doesn't make sense. If the crank has no academic affiliation, arXiv will need an endorser http://arxiv.org/help/endorsement so the crank will simply return to writing mathematicians to find an endorser.

Comment: You show little knowledge of Ramanujan's story.

Answer (score -2):

I think a good policy would be to redirect those people to [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/). Let them open a new topic to ask what's wrong with their proof.

If it's trivial to find errors then someone one Math Overflow will point out those errors. If their proof actually works I would expect someone at Math Overflow to recognise working proof.

You only need to write a email to redirect people to MathOverflow once and afterwards you can send everyone who sends you unsolicited proofs the same canned email.

Comment: Please, no. We get plenty of these at MO already, and they get closed immediately because their questions are incoherent.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer : If the main reason they get closed is incoherence, the person who asks the question has feedback and could hopefully ask a better question next time

Comment: Please don't send amateurs to MathOverflow. This is explicitly not the purpose of MO, so the question will be quickly closed, leaving the amateur unhappy because they were specifically told to post it there. Even aside from the purpose of MO, it can be difficult to convince cranks that there's something wrong with their proof. One critical professional skill is writing clear, readable proofs that are precise and explicit enough that one can point out unambiguous errors if they are present. If someone doesn't yet have that skill, then trying to sort out their manuscript can be an awful mess.

Comment: @Christian: Maybe a better suggestion would be to redirect those amateurs at first to MSE rather than to MO. If nobody makes a comment regarding the flaw of the proof then he may wish to post his proof in MO.