# Is it safe to post one's research on web sites like Math Overflow for "peer review" before submitting to a journal?

Tags: mathematics, peer-review, website

Suppose in mathematics, someone finds a completely new elementary proof of a famous theorem and wants his work ''peer reviewed'' on a site like MathOverflow or MathStackExchange before submitting to a formal journal. How safe would this be ?

Comment: It is NOT safe, at all. A formal journal or a conference "with determined privacy policies" would be considered for "peer reviewing", not such a web site...

Comment: Mathoverflow and Math.SE are not for peer review. Your post will be closed very quickly.

Comment: "someone finds a completely new **elementary proof** of a **famous theorem** and wants his work ''peer reviewed'' on a site like MathOverflow or MathStackExchange" -- then they are probably not experts (or else they would know to publish in a journal), hence their proof is most likely wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately you're asking a good question, "can you crowdsource peer review," and a bad question, "what if I find an elementary proof of Fermat's last theorem and tell people about it," which have a bit different answers. I suggest editing your example to something less crank-ish.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni but even when it's closed, the post notice will contain helpful links to show how should one can improve the post?

Comment: @Ooker There is little hope to 'improve' a post on a subject that is completely off-topic.

Answer (score 53):

If you post under your real name, I think that it is quite "safe" in the sense that your work is unlikely to get stolen because of this.  In fact, posting your work on a public forum is the best defense I know against intellectual theft.

On the other hand, "Is this proof of a known result correct?" is generally not regarded as an appropriate MathOverflow question.  There can be a fine line between asking questions that come up in one's research and asking others to vet your research.  The former is the purpose of the site, whereas the latter is discouraged.  Your question seems to fall on the wrong side.  I think it would stay open, at least, on math.stackexchange.com.

If you have not already published work in the past, I might recommend that you try to get one-on-one help from a qualified (and trusted) mentor, rather than trying to crowd-vet your proof.  It is not impossible to do research mathematics completely independently and with no academic affiliation -- I have seen people do so quite well -- but it is very rare and *much* harder than doing it with some assistance.  It would be reasonable to seek help from the math department of any university near you.  If the mathematicians you get in contact with can't help you, see if they can connect you to someone who can.

**Postscript**: I have observed on this site and others that amateur mathematicians often have significant concerns that their work will be stolen.  I think these sentiments are very unfortunate, because they can serve to prevent these people from getting what would benefit them most: qualified help and supervision.  I don't want to say that it is strictly impossible for someone's work to get stolen, but here are two things: (i) I have done mathematics for my entire adult life (more than 20 years), and I have **never** seen or heard of an amateur mathematician's work being stolen by a professional mathematician.  Reports of theft of mathematical work of anyone by anyone have come to me...but very, very rarely.  (ii) I would estimate that about 90% of the work done by amateur mathematicians is not publishable.  This is not to say that most amateur mathematicians are hopeless or incapable of doing real, publishable work.  However most professional mathematicians train for years and make use of enormous amounts of human capital in order to get to the point where they can do and write up publishable work.  If they had been afraid of showing their work to their mentors, they would not have gotten anywhere in most cases.  Just something to think about.

Answer (score 12):

If you are an 'outsider' to the mathematical community and you have an argument which you believe provides a significant mathematical advance, you may well have broken new ground - but you should also seriously consider the possibility that your argument contains a mistake, and you should carefully think about your interactions with the mathematical community in that light.

I don't say this to discourage you, but I do want to impress upon you that you are part of a relatively large community of people who will look much like you to a mathematician - see for example the questions [Handling unsolicited proofs of famous mathematical problems](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20674/handling-unsolicited-proofs-of-famous-mathematical-problems) and [I believe I have solved a famous open problem. How do I convince people in the field that I am not a crank?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18491/i-believe-i-have-solved-a-famous-open-problem-how-do-i-convince-people-in-the-f) on this site, which give a good impression of the volume of similar requests your work is likely to be embedded in. Again, this is not to discourage you, but to encourage you to think carefully, and take your time over, how you engage with professional mathematicians you are asking to review your work. If nothing else, make sure you read and mull over all the answers on both threads.

That said, when you do communicate your findings to outsiders, you are justified in seeking protection for your work so it isn't later claimed by someone else as their own. I would generally advise you to take it easy on such protections: your main problem is overwhelmingly more likely to be getting mathematicians to take your manuscript seriously, not defending it from theft.

In that regard, the best defence I can think of is to *make it publicly available, as widely as possible, under your real name*. This can include posting your manuscript to the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org) if [you can post there](http://arxiv.org/help/endorsement), to [viXra](http://vixra.org/) as an alternative, or to sites like MathOverflow or Math Stack Exchange. For good measure, if you post on Stack Exchange, you might want to ensure that your post is archived on the [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/). It's important to note that even then, your work is not "safe" in that someone else could, in principle, take that work and submit it as their own to a journal.

However, this is academic misconduct of pretty much the highest order, and if that were to happen you should contact the journal editor and the dean of the author's institution with proof (like your MathOverflow post!) that you are the original author of the unattributed work. That is immediate grounds for an investigation which can result in retraction of the paper and severe academic sanctions against that author. If it ever comes to that.

It is also important to note that, regardless of whether your work is safe or not, it may or may not be appropriate to make such a request of MO or MSE. In particular, the threads [Using Math Overflow to check whether or not a proof is correct](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1265/using-math-overflow-to-check-whether-or-not-a-proof-is-correct), [On discussion of published papers at MO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2328/on-discussion-of-published-papers-at-mo), and [Appropriate or not: “To what extent are the results in Paper X correct?”](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2762/appropriate-or-not-to-what-extent-are-the-results-in-paper-x-correct) indicate that such a request would be considered off-topic at MathOverflow. To tie this in with my initial point, posting review requests in inappropriate venues is a good way to quickly exhaust the goodwill of the mathematical community and make it much harder for your work to receive appropriate vetting even if it deserves it.

So what should you do? I would start with [this advice](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/18570/820).

Comment: This is a very good answer (and similar to mine, which I wrote rather slowly).  I want to point out one thing: "It's important to note that even then, your work is not "safe" in that someone else could, in principle, take that work and submit it as their own to a journal." You're not wrong, but I think it's even more important to note that all mathematical work is not "safe" in this sense.  Already published work, including of establishing and famous mathematicians, can also be improperly appropriated and published in this way...and in fact I think that kind of theft is more common.

Comment: I would actually advice against uploading to viXra. To many, that would be a signal that the author did not want to do the minimal amount of work required to be able to upload to arXiv instead (even if this is not true).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That is true - a manuscript in viXra is definitely a strong signal that many will take negatively. However, it is easy to forget from within an academic institution that not everyone can post to the arXiv, and that the 'minimal work' of finding endorsers is precisely what we're advising the OP to do carefully. As regards the question, the OP would be justifiably worried that, if they send a manuscript to an arXiv endorser, that person could 'steal' the work. A viXra submission - even if suitably undisclosed to such a potential endorser - is a powerful insurance policy.

Comment: I disagree strongly that the OP would be justified in their worry, as long as they actually put some thought into their choice of person to contact. The worry might seem justified by someone from the outside, but that does not make it so.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I agree that it is highly unlikely that a potential endorser would steal work sent for such purposes. However, you cannot fault an outsider for considering that unsafe (even if it probably isn't). In any case, saying that posting on the arXiv requires minimal work is disingenuous at best.

Comment: Compared to actually writing a paper worth putting on arXiv, it really is minimal (it might take some time, but that does not increase the amount of work).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Apologies, but that really is disingenuous, and it is based on the fact that someone with an academic email address can simply go and post; without one, you can't. Instead, you need to find and convince suitable endorsers that your manuscript is arXiv-ready, which means you need to get endorsers to read it and you need them to respond to your emails to begin with, which means that you need to tackle [all the challenges](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/18570) of getting taken seriously. Calling this minimal is like laughing from atop the ivory tower.

Comment: Sending an email with the paper and a request for endrsement takes a few minutes. The waiting time until getting (or not getting) an answer is not work, it is time that can be spend doing other stuff.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm not sure at all that encouraging such people to take that step lightly is at all helpful. (I wonder, for example, if you'd advise people as nonchalantly to send unsolicited email if you yourself received a significant volume of such emails on a regular basis.) Pressing 'send' is easy; it's getting the email right that we should be advising people to do carefully (which Kaveh and Pete Clark have done well). Simply put: I disagree with you. But we should probably leave it at that.

Answer (score 9):

If you say you have found a completely new elementary proof of a famous theorem, you instantly put yourself into the 'nutcase' box until you can prove otherwise (or unless you have already proved otherwise). Posting on MathOverflow is a good step to additonally move into the 'nuisance' box as well. Even if you are right, you have not attached your name to the proof in any formal way, so someone could steal it. Probably the route that is most likely to win you acceptance within the mathematical community is to find someone at a university or similar who is willing to mentor you, and don't conclude your proof is correct until you can actually convince another mathematician it is correct. If it really is elementary then that shouldn't prove so difficult.

Comment: "If you say you have found a completely new elementary proof of a famous theorem, you instantly put yourself into the 'nutcase' box until you can prove otherwise" That seems harsh to me.  E.g. 'There are infinitely many prime numbers 'is a (very) famous theorem, and completely new elementary proofs are often found.  "Even if you are right, you have not attached your name to the proof in any formal way, so someone could steal it." I really don't agree with that: if you post the question under your real name, then you are identified as the author.  I don't see what formality has to do with it.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Ok, yes, you're right. I took the question to mean an elementary proof of a result that doesn't currently have one. The question does suggest the intention is to publish in a journal, which would not be a realistic option if many elementary proofs exist. Posting under your real name would attach your name to it, but there's no system to guarantee who chose the name. It might sound silly to wrongly give credit to someone else for a right result, but could you similarly post poor-quality work using someone's name?

Comment: The line *"don't conclude your proof is correct until you can actually convince another mathematician it is correct. If it really is elementary then that shouldn't prove so difficult."* is pure gold.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark So you're saying I can steal someone's idea, post it on Stack Exchange under my real name, and I'm identified as the author? I don't think so. Being the first person to post it in an online forum proves nothing - at best it is evidence that can lend weight to an argument which is supported by other evidence.

Comment: "Posting under your real name would attach your name to it, but there's no system to guarantee who chose the name." I'm not sure I completely understood this.  There's no system to guarantee that the names appearing in most published papers are not completely made up (and every once in a while, they are); institutional affiliations are not always required and rarely vetted.  Anyway, if the identity cannot be verified, then the post itself would be cited by any mathematician using the work.  I find the idea that people can steal your ideas if you don't present them "formally" quite bizarre.

Comment: @JessicaB: "The question does suggest the intention is to publish in a journal, which would not be a realistic option if many elementary proofs exist." A colleague and I are running a graduate seminar on the process of mathematical research. We began with the theorem that there are infinitely many primes, and at one stage asked the students to find all papers in the last five years that give new proofs and/or generalizations of this result. We got about 50 papers. New, elementary proofs of famous theorems are published very often: not in Inventiones, but in other journals

Comment: @JBentley: "So you're saying I can steal someone's idea, post it on Stack Exchange under my real name, and I'm identified as the author?" No.  "I don't think so." OK, good.  In case it is necessary, let me say that you should not try to steal someone else's mathematical idea.  This will likely work out badly for you: it could be the end of your mathematical career.  By the way, I have several times used postings of mine and others math.SE and mathoverflow.net in my later published papers.  I have never had any problems.  If you have different experiences, please let me know.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Seriously? Clearly I picked the wrong topic. But I'd be curious to know for how many of those papers the proof you're refering to is the main focus of the paper.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I think you missed my point. I'm not suggesting that I'm considering stealing anyone's idea. I also don't dispute that you might be able to post your ideas and have no issues result from it (i.e. my point is not about whether you increase you risk of theft). I was responding to your assertion that, *"if you post the question under your real name, then you are identified as the author"*. That is not the case, because a thief has just as much ability to post material under his real name, as the real author. The mere act of posting it proves nothing by itself.

Comment: @JBentley But the time stamps on different posting or dates of publication would serve as evidence to figure out who had the idea first. If person A posts their new proof on mathoverflow, and then person B takes it and sends it to a journal, person A could be able to claim priority for it. I don't know if such a controversy has ever happened in real life.

Comment: @JBentley: By the author, I meant the author *of the post*.  This is a response to an answer claiming that one must communicate one's ideas in a certain "formal" way in order to get credit for them.  My response is: no, as long as you see that Person X said Y, if you use it in your work, you must mention that X said Y; there are no further bells and whistles involved.  If Y is plagiarized from person Z, then this identification is problematic, but I am not talking about that.  Anyway, in what context have you ever had to *prove* that you are the author of a mathematical document?

Comment: @user90219 how do you figure that the timestamp proves who had the idea first? All it proves is *who posted it first*. By your reasoning, B could steal someone's idea, post it to get a timestamp, and then "prove" that he had the idea first.

Comment: @Pete ok, I see your point now.