# Submitting an unsolved-problem paper to open access journals

Tags: publications

If a person without good records and with bad records (many flawed papers on arxiv) submits a paper which claims a proof of the Riemann Hypothesis to a traditional journal, then will it be ignored certainly?

If so, then will it make any good for him to submit it to an open-access journal
which accepts articles in two weeks?

I would like to know if the International Journal of Mathematics and Mathematical Sciences is still active or not. I think they used to receive many submissions but now they seem not. I, for one, like their special interests in publishing unsolved problems.

Thanks.

Comment: If the "open-access journal" is legitimate, it will reject the paper in the same way a traditional one would.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I seem to have grown up somehow, as I found an error in my idea, by the way.

Comment: It is good that you found your error **before** publishing it in a no-peer-review journal, thus adding yet another "bad" paper to your list.

Answer (score 11):

> If a person without good records and with bad records (many flawed papers on arxiv) submits a paper which claims a proof of the Riemann Hypothesis to a traditional journal, then will it be ignored certainly?

This person will have to make a very, very, very convincing case in order to be taken seriously. See [I believe I have solved a famous open problem. How do I convince people in the field that I am not a crank?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18491/i-believe-i-have-solved-a-famous-open-problem-how-do-i-convince-people-in-the-f), especially the [answer by Kaveh](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/18570/11365).

> If so, then will it make any good for him to submit it to an open-access journal which accepts articles in two weeks?

This will not lead to the paper being taken seriously by the research community. If that is your goal, don't waste your money.

Comment: Unless the proof is trivial, how can a journal accept a proof of a well-known difficult problem in 2 weeks? There's no peer review going on there, surely. Nobody is going to trust this paper. Even the secretive Andrew Wiles sought out a trustworthy and knowledgeable friend to discuss the correctness of his Fermat proof, and, whoever claims to solve Riemann is well advised to do the same.