# What is the formal process for a theory to get accepted by the science community?

Tags: publications, conference, physics, science, philosophy

**Question description so that anyone can evaluate and answer accordingly**

Since last many years, I have self-studied a subject that is Theoretical Physics - Cosmology, Time and Space. I have never got the opportunity to study this at University level so I self-published a book on the theory which I have researched.

I don't know what is the formal process for a theory to get accepted by the science community, please guide me on how to proceed further?

The link provided in the comment section is different as it was more about publishing a paper in a science journal...

However, I got an answer below that there is no formal process and there are options of publishing a paper in a reputed journal or participating in the conference... I am looking for more options if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I believe I have solved a famous open problem. How do I convince people in the field that I am not a crank?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18491/i-believe-i-have-solved-a-famous-open-problem-how-do-i-convince-people-in-the-f)

Comment: It was all about publishing a paper in a science journal... however I got an answer below that this is the only way by publishing a paper in reputed journal or conference.. thanks it helped

Answer (score 5):

There is no formal process. But before much of anything can happen, a new theory needs to be widely seen and evaluated. A period of independent verification of its predictions needs to happen. This was the case even for Einstein.

But self publishing a book is not a great way to disseminate your ideas as it will probably be seen by very few people unless you are already very prominent.

In the case of Einstein, in fact, there were, at the time, more or less generally accepted competing theories and those who held them were resistant to accept his ideas, but were also very powerful. As they "left the scene", his ideas became more accepted by younger physicists, but it also took experimental verification for the ideas to become dominant.

If you want to have your ideas widely disseminated, you need to publish in accepted journals or have them presented at conferences.

Comment: I would add that a formal process, if it existed, would only lead to abuse with no benefits.

Comment: @buffy Thanks for your answer... Short and straightforward... however I was wondering if there are some more options available or not.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist ... can't agree or disagree as of now because I am struggling to get my paper to publish due to lack of academic background and language technicality.

Answer (score 1):

As Buffy said, the first step toward "getting a theory accepted" is publishing it in a peer-reviewed journal.

Few people will read your self-published book*.  Submitting a paper to a peer-reviewed journal will at least get it read by a few people in the process of considering it for publication.  Then, if the paper is publised, many more will see it, and some of them will even read it.

*Even books on the top of the New York Times bestseller list are often bunk.  For example, we can often see such books with spurious medical or dietary claims.

Comment: This answer is missing the "no".

Comment: The sentence that begins "Submitting a paper ..." may be too optimistic. An editor might read only a fraction of the paper before desk-rejecting it.