# Complaining about a published paper

Tags: publications, research-process, citations, thesis, peer-review

I have seen a paper recently published in a reputable IEEE journal but this paper is completely wrong, using other algorithms and making false statements.  This is degrading the complete research quality. How can we complain regarding the journal with proof.

Comment: The response would be... the paper has undergone a rigorous review.    -- i.e., go away.

Comment: If it's an academic misconduct, e.g., plagiarism, just send an email to the Editor in Chief with your evidence.  He/she will be more than happy to follow that up.

Comment: can we inform the editor about misconduct anonymously. The main agenda is to inform the misconduct with proof . Will they reveal the identity

Comment: Re anonymous complaints. If I were an editor of such a journal, complaints with no name on them would get very low priority. Complaints asking their name be kept confidential might get higher priority but still less than from people prepared to speak openly.

Comment: By the way, before you make any complaint, just check extremely carefully that you are correct. Double-triple check. Try looking at the paper from as many contexts as you can reasonably come up with. Check with a trusted colleague that you are correct. Making complaints of this kind and being wrong would be quite embarrassing.

Comment: Sir, I have checked very carefully, one by one line is copied in the algorithm and claimed as the proposed one. Few sentenced are changes like grammatically changed. Based on the algorithm, they provided the results which have no relation with the algorithm, random results are presented. I feel very bad when I look at such kind of research in a reputable journal.  I have seen some other papers of this author and everywhere such kind of work is published.  Please show me some way that I can provide the proof anonymously because indirectly I know that person. I don't wanna reveal my identity.

Answer (score 3):

Is the paper wrong in the sense that it is incorrect? Or is it wrong in the sense that it is bogus, to the point where one wonders how the journal could possibly have published such nonsense?

In the former scenario: you don't complain. You write a new paper that says the original paper is wrong because [reasons]. You can submit it to the same journal, although you don't have to.

In the latter scenario: write to the editor and tell them your concerns. Be ready to back up your claims, because the result you're seeking (retraction) is a serious one. Alternatively, you can criticize the paper on social media. If enough people agree with you, you can cause quite some waves ([example](http://rrresearch.fieldofscience.com/2011/03/is-this-claim-of-bacteria-in-meteorite.html)). Of course, you also risk looking like an idiot if you turn out to be wrong.

Comment: Sir, in this paper serious misconduct is there, an algorithm directly copied from other papers and claimed as the proposed one. I was shocked by looking at this and completely false statements and results are there. I don't k ow how to report regarding this. It really misleading the readers and lowering the quality of research. Is there by way to report anonymously.

Comment: If you want to be taken seriously, [use your real name](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18491/i-believe-i-have-solved-a-famous-open-problem-how-do-i-convince-people-in-the-f/18570#18570). "Not using your real name indicates that you are trying to avoid suffering any potential negative consequence of your claim being incorrect. Using your real name indicates that you are sure enough to be ready to suffer potential negative professional consequences if you are mistaken, so you can be taken more seriously. If you are not completely sure about your claim do not waste her time."

Comment: I am pretty sure about it with proof. is there any way to publically expose it. Then others will also find it. Nowadays,  researchers want to increase the number of publications with false research also.

Comment: I think I described how to do so in the answer; is any part unclear?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your criticisms against a published paper public, you can use the platform [PubPeer](https://pubpeer.com/).

Comment: On PubPeer , can a person show the misconduct with proof without using any negative statement? This way others can easily judge the content.

Comment: Yes, sure, @Makkythomas; it all depends on your wording.

Comment: Can I show the scientific misconduct here with proof to tet help from other researchers over it. I am.new to this but such kind  of scientific misconduct really disappoints me