# Collatz conjecture proof

Tags: journals, paper-submission, review-articles

A while ago a submitted an article to ENT about the Collatz conjecture, it consists the proof that I derived from within the structure stress theory which is a theory a I devolved to view the Riemann hypothesis. I didn't need to show case this concept in the Collatz conjecture article, I only used the concept to extract the properties needed to to prove the conjecture.
ENT had asked for expert opinion about my article, I've had communicated my finding with a professor that asked to put his name as an author, which I disagreed with.
Note that he did not contribute in any way rather reading and understanding, which I hoped that he would certify that my finding is true to ENT.
Any idea how to publish the paper.

Comment: You say you submitted the paper already. What more are you looking for?

Comment: A related but essential issue is that it's very unlikely you've proven the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: @Buffy ENT asked for an expert opinion in order for them to look into the article, as dismissed it to a day  I make that happen.

Comment: @user176372 I did proved it, I just need some who can see how I did it and certifies to ENT that I did.

Comment: What is ENT? Sorry, but I'm not familiar with it (Certainly not Ear, Nose, Throat, which is what Google thinks it is).

Comment: @Buffy it is essential number theory journal by mathematical science publishers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I believe I have solved a famous open problem. How do I convince people in the field that I am not a crank?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18491/i-believe-i-have-solved-a-famous-open-problem-how-do-i-convince-people-in-the-f)

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're unfamiliar with how the peer review process works.

1. You submit the paper.
2. The journal will have editors, who will usually send your paper to peer reviewers, who are often professors.
3. The reviewer will check the validity of your proof. They will not usually be listed as an author, and you will not usually know who they are.
4. If the reviewer verifies your proof, and the editor agrees with them, then your paper gets published.

What you're describing does not fit into this workflow, suggesting something is wrong with your description. In particular, this sentence does not make sense:

> ENT had asked for expert opinion about my article, I've had communicated my finding with a professor that asked to put his name as an author

If ENT is the name of a journal and they asked for expert opinion on your article (i.e. sent your paper to review), you will not usually be contacted by a professor who wants to be an author.

So: check your description. If you were contacted by a professor who wants to be an author, odds are they are not affiliated with ENT. You wait until ENT reaches a decision. They say yes, your paper gets published. They say no, you find another journal.

Comment: This journal may not, actually, have reviewers. It seems to be entirely open access. The editorial board seems legit, though. And, finding reviewers for such a paper might be hard unless it is obviously  flawed.

Comment: @Buffy: Essential Number Theory certainly does have reviewers. See, for instance, the section "peer review" on their [about page](https://msp.org/ent/about/journal/about.html).

Comment: ENT is covered by MathSciNet, which suggests to me it is a legitimate math journal.